# Is it possible to resize the website showing in UIWebView?

Tags: iphone, ios4, uiwebview

I am showing my website in UIWebView but as it is too large, it is showing that much large in my iPhone screen too.

Is there any way to scale it down to show it property fit in iPhone screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can fit the page..

Like for example

```
fblikeWebView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
```

This will fit your page in the webview.

Cheers